# Check nested object key[value] in Mongoose array, before an update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use `$addToSet` to insert new Objects into an Array in mongo using mongoose:

I have a two models:

```
var itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  itemId: Number,
  save_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  items: [itemSchema]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I would like to use mongoose to add an `item` into the `items` array, but only if that item does not exist.

Currently, using `$addToSet` is still adding duplicates because, I assume **the save_date stamp is different for every item**:

```
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      id,
      {$addToSet: {item: {itemId: newItem} } },
      {upsert: true},
      function (err, saveItem){
        if (err) {return handleError(err)};
        res.send(saveItem);
      }
  );
```

Which results in a user entry:

```
"name": "Vinnie James"
"items" : [
        {
            "itemId" : 123,
            "_id" : ObjectId("587b10259233c524454d745d"),
            "save_date" : ISODate("2017-01-15T06:01:09.850Z")
        },
        {
            "itemId" : 123,
            "_id" : ObjectId("587b17398ed7052b1e5196bc"),
            "save_date" : ISODate("2017-01-15T06:31:21.263Z")
        }
    ]
```

Is it possible to check if the `itemId` exists before adding the entry, in order to avoid having two `"itemId": 123` as seen above?

If there is a better way to structure the model to achieve the same result, I'm happy to consider that as well

Comment: I'm thinking I could first run a db query for the item and only do the update if the `itemId` doesnt exist, but this feels a little round-a-bout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
   {_id: id, "items.itemId": {$nin:[newItem.itemId]}},
   {$push: {items: newItem }},
   {new: true}
   function (err, updatedUser){
      if (err) {return handleError(err)};
      res.send(updatedUser);
   }
);
```

`$nin` operator will ensure that there is not item in items with the same `itemId` of `newItem`. Then if it succeed the `newItem` will be added by `$push` operator. `{new: true}` tells mongo to pass the updated document in the provided callback

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!